# How to generate a markov chain with a 2-parameter gamma marginal?

Tags: time-series, markov-process, gamma-distribution

I want to generate a time series where the individual variables form a Markov Chain and where the marginal distribution is a 2-parameter Gamma.  How do I do this?

Comment: The simplest way is to just generate each observation from the same 2-parameter Gamma distribution; the observations follow a Markov process and the marginal distribution is clearly the aforementioned 2-parameter Gamma.

Comment: Thank you @jbowman!  Now, if I want the observations to be correlated with parameter $\rho$ - how do I do this and make sure the marginal distribution remains the 2-parameter gamma?